# Long click on edittext do not override toolbar, android

Tags: android, android-toolbar

when i long click the edit text the toolbar was being move down on screenshot 2, how to replace the toolbar with the text editor?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcxHd.jpg < screenshots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your app theme you need to set

```
<item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
```

this will make action mode overlay your actionbar.

Comment: @ipauler : how to change status bar color as in toolbar?

Comment: @Viks here's solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29618470/change-status-bar-color-when-entering-contextual-action-mode